# I have a problem to install (psych) package

Tags: r

```
> install.packages("psych")
WARNING: Rtools is required to build R packages but is not currently installed. Please download and install the appropriate version of Rtools before proceeding:

https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/Rtools/
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/Ali Basuony/Documents/R/win-library/3.6’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning in install.packages :
  dependency ‘mnormt’ is not available
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.6/psych_1.9.12.31.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 3800520 bytes (3.6 MB)
downloaded 3.6 MB

package ‘psych’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

The downloaded binary packages are in
    C:\Users\Ali Basuony\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpeYduMH\downloaded_packages
> install.packages(‘mnormt’)
Error: unexpected input in "install.packages(‘"
> install.packages("mnormt")
WARNING: Rtools is required to build R packages but is not currently installed. Please download and install the appropriate version of Rtools before proceeding:

https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/Rtools/
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/Ali Basuony/Documents/R/win-library/3.6’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘mnormt’ is not available (for R version 3.6.3)
```

Comment: Looks like you need to install RTools. The error messages can be very helpful in these situations!

Answer (score 2):

The problem is described here:

> WARNING: Rtools is required to build R packages but is not currently installed. Please
> download and install the appropriate version of Rtools before proceeding:
> https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/Rtools/

So you have two options:

### Install RTools

You need Rtools to build packages from source on Windows. So visit this page:

- https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/history.html

and download appropriate version of Rtools to your R version (it seems to be [Rtools35](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/Rtools35.exe) as you probably have `R 3.6.3`). Note that it's about 1 GB on your hard drive.

### Install binary packages

Or if you don't want to install Rtools, you maybe can try to install binary packages and not bother with building it from source. Then run this:

```
install.packages("psych", type = "binary", dependencies = TRUE)
install.packages("mnormt", type = "binary", dependencies = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

The current `mnormt` package depends on R version 4.0.0 or greater.  You need to update R to install it, or install an older version.  To install an older version you'll need Rtools.